# PhysX Terrain - Heightfield vs TriangleMesh

Tags: c++, mesh, heightmap, physx

I'm working on a project in which I need to create a terrain in my PhysX application.

As input data I have dted file (elevation).

Which is the better way for create a terrain in PhysX?
I need to have a large terrain.

I have try to create an HeightField but I have found that sample array dimension is limited to 255.999 value (with 260.000 I have a crash). It's correct this observation? This means that I need multiple Heightfield for create a large terrain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Heightfield method is way better for terrain, I have a terrain running here with heightfield and I can easily change it to triangleMesh, and the performance drop isn't small.

And also, I've noticed the limitation you mentioned, but in my case my game uses an infinite terrain and a paging system, so I never actually had this crash...

Then, probably the way for you to use heightfield for large terrain is paging them OR having multiple (as you already said). Implementing a simple paging system shouldn't cost you much, and there are lots of advantages, for instance, you only actually load the physX heightfield around your character (even though the graphical mesh is being rendered) which improves a lot performance.

Best.